# Python "guess the number" game always returns the same answer

Tags: python, random

I wrote this script but it always returns the same answer ("Your guess is too high"), no matter what the user inputs. Any insight would be helpful.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 10) 

guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")

if type(guess == int):
    print(number) # this prints the randint to show the code isn't working

    while(number != 0):
        if(guess > number):
            print("Your guess is too high!")
            break

        elif(guess < number):
            print("That's too low.")
            break

        elif(guess == number):
            print("Thats's right!")
            break

    else:
        print("Please enter a number.")
```

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://ideone.com/cMCOHZ)

Comment: So I deleted my answer because some people decided to downvote without explaining why. Your code worked fine on Python 2.7 -  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RTsuo.png - though there are scopes of improvements, the code does work on Python 2.

Comment: The `while` loop is worthless; you don't change the value of `number` inside the loop, and you break out of it in every case anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is useless, the problem of testing the input as an int is better handled with a try/except.

All together the correct answer is in Python3 :

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 10) 
found = False

while  not found:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        if guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too high!")
        elif guess < number:
            print("That's too low.")
        elif guess == number:
            print("Thats's right!")
            found = True    
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number.")
```

Comment: Probably should not print the number  ;)  You could also just move the  `guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))` inside the try

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You are perfectly right ... i copied print from question and input can be kept inside the try. Will edit to clean code

Comment: Awesome! This worked very well. Now the code allows the user to keep guessing until the number is found.

I don't understand how True/False and try statements work, so I'll read up on them to learn why this script works. Any suggestions for best resources on these topics?

Comment: while here is just a loop where we stay while our boolean found is false. try/except checks if something unusual happens like not beeing able to convert the input to an int. You can read a tutorial like https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/.

Comment: I understand now how the "found = False" and "while not found" boolean logic works. To figure it out, I changed the "found" var to True, changed the while loop to "while found", and then changed the "found" var before the exception handler to False, and the code still works perfectly. Same logic, just in reverse. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
if type(guess == int):
```

This isn't doing what you expect. It always returns `True` because it's the equivalent to `bool(type(False))`. First make sure to convert your input to an `int`

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
```

and then remove this `if` statement:

```
if type(guess == int):
```

Your problem is that this code:

```
 if(guess > number)
```

is always comparing a `string` to an `int`, so once you correct that your code will be fixed.

Comment: OP should be prepared for `int()` to throw an exception if they always convert the user input.

Answer (score 2):

I have just copied and pasted your code and it seems to function mostly correctly. There are some issues with it though. First, it appears that this is written for python 2 based on the way you are using the input function. However this is bad practice as the `input()` function in python 2 includes an implicit call to the `eval()` function which could allow for arbitrary code to be run.

In python 2 the better practice would be to use `guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))`.

In python 3, `raw_input()` has been removed and `input()` replaces it. So in python 3 you would use `guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))`.

Your final `else` block is also indented where it should not be, although if you revise your code to make use of the advice given above, your `if...else` block is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `input` returns a string in Python 3. You need to call `int()` to make it an integer type:

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
```

You're also using the `type()` function incorrectly. You probably want the function `isinstance()`: `if isinstance(guess, int):`

Also, in Python, we don't need parentheses like you've used. You can simply do `if guess > number:`